# Interface Mismatch Property Accessor

Tags: c#, syntax, accessor

I have a simple Interface which I would like to implement with different Accessors

```
public interface IValidatorByState : IValidator
{
    AuthorizedDbContext Context { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to implement this on a class with an Public, Or Protected Get and an  Internal Set;

**Edit**  This class is is exposed to the user, they should only be able to retrieve the Context.

```
public class ValidatorByState<TEntity> : AbstractValidator<TEntity>, IValidatorByState
{
    public AuthorizedDbContext Context { get; internal set;}
}
```

No matter which way Implement this I've been given an error

Attempts:

```
public AuthorizedDbContext Context { get; internal set;}
```

> ValidatorByState.Context is not public

```
protected AuthorizedDbContext Context { get; internal set;}
```

> ValidatorByState.Context.set Accessor must be more restrictive than property,

```
AuthorizedDbContext _context;
public AuthorizedDbContext IValidatorByState.Context => this._context;
public AuthorizedDbContext IValidatorByState.Context {
    set { this._context = value; }
}
```

For this I get an error on both stating

> Explicit implementation missing Accessor

How can I have a public get method with a internal set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a public interface that was readonly and internal interface with the setter methods/properties. The internal interface has to be explicitly implementated:

```
public interface IValidatorByStateReadOnly 
{
    AuthorizedDbContext Context { get; }
}  

internal interface IValidatorByState : IValidatorByStateReadOnly
{
    new AuthorizedDbContext Context { get; set; }
}

public class ValidatorByState<TEntity> : IValidatorByState
{
    private AuthorizedDbContext _context;

    public AuthorizedDbContext Context => _context;

    AuthorizedDbContext IValidatorByState.Context 
    {
        get => _context;
        set => _context = value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooo, this is even better. Lemme check now I think this is perfect

Answer (score 2):

Interface members must be public.

What about of:

```
public interface IValidatorByStateReader
{
    AuthorizedDbContext Context { get; }
}

internal interface IValidatorByStateWriter
{
    AuthorizedDbContext Context { set; }
}

public class ValidatorByState<TEntity> : IValidatorByStateReader, IValidatorByStateWriter
{
    private AuthorizedDbContext _context;
    AuthorizedDbContext IValidatorByStateReader.Context => this._context;
    AuthorizedDbContext IValidatorByStateWriter.Context { set => this._context = value; }
}
```

Comment: This might work, but  now when I have a map ValidatorByStates I won't be able to set their context with out casting to both interfaces.

Comment: Interface members do not have to public. They must be public to use implicit implementation. Explicit implementations can only be called through a reference to the interface.

Comment: This answer does not work, this exposes Context Property Still to the user.

Comment: @SantiagoRegojo ValidatorByState<TEntity> is a class which will be implement by the user i am writing a framework

Comment: They will still be able to set the public context, they just won't be able to access the interface

Comment: you can use explicit implementations of the write/read intefaces